# Is there a word for "reading slowly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I thought a few good options would be "*amble*"; "*slog*"; "*plod*" - but they are mostly used in context of walking.

I want to use the word in a sentence like -

> I *(insert word)* over a book for days.

Comment: I ***pored over*** the book for days.

Answer (score 0):

**Perusing** usually involves taking your time to read something.

> Verb: **peruse**  pu'rooz
>
> 1. Examine or consider with attention and in detail
>
>    "Please peruse this report at your leisure"
>
> Derived forms: perusing, peruses, perused
>
> Type of: examine, see

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=peruse)

Comment: The reason I don't find this word appropriate is that it doesn't tell about the struggle, dreariness of reading.